# Updating a table based on whether another table's records exist and are > 60

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

```
update COLORS
set    COLORS.AR = 'RED'
where  COLORS.GCRS = 'FIRST' 
and    (case when max(NEWAPP."AGE") > 60 
and    count(NEWAPP."AGE") > 0)
```

I get an error that says "group function is not allowed here"

Does anyone know what I can do to prevent this error?

The title pretty much says everything I can about the objective.

Comment: `NEWAPP`, I assume, is another table.  Is there some relationship between the `NEWAPP` table and the `AR` table?  Or do you really only care that there is some row in the `NEWAPP` table with an `AGE` that is greater than 60? Normally, you'd want to do some sort of join to determine whether a row existed in `NEWAPP` that was related to the `AR` row in some way and had a particular value.

Comment: All I'm really concerned about is whether there is any record within NEWAPP."AGE" whose value exceeds 60

Comment: OK.  Is `colors.ar` the name of a table?  Or of a column in the table?  You're using it as both (you're updating a table named `colors.ar` and setting a column named `colors.ar`).  That isn't possible-- either one or the other must be incorrect.

Comment: colors is the name of the table
ar is the name of the column
poor naming convention, my apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there really is no relationship between the tables

```
UPDATE colors
   SET colors.ar = 'RED'
 WHERE colors.gcrs = 'FIRST'
   AND EXISTS( SELECT 1
                 FROM newapp
                WHERE age > 60 )
```

It would be very unusual, though, in a proper data model to have a situation where you want to do an uncorrelated subquery like this.  Normally, there would be some column that relates the `colors` table to the `newapp` table and you would want an additional predicate in the `EXISTS` subquery for that relationship.

Comment: This works very well, thank you. I know the tables I am working with are awful. Part of the reason I am writing this query in the first place actually. Was I getting the "group function" error because I was trying to use both a count and a max in the same where clause?

Comment: @user1821973- You were getting the `ORA-00934` because you had an aggregate function as a predicate which is not allowed.  But even without that, you would have received an error because your `CASE` statement was malformed (no `then`, `else`, or `end`), because `boolean` is not a valid data type in SQL (assuming that you were expecting the `case` statement to return a boolean), and because you were trying to reference a table that you hadn't selected from (in addition to the issue with the name of the table that has been corrected).